# UTF-8のファイルをSJISに変換後で文字化け。

Tags: java

サクラエディタを使って文字コード「UTF-8」を指定して保存したＣＳＶファイルをJAVAでSJISに変換してファイルの中身をコンソールに表示したいのですが日本語の表示のところで文字化けが出ている形です。
なぜでしょうか。どう修正すれば文字化けがなくコンソール表示できるのでしょうか。
●ＣＳＶファイルの中身
no,title,year
1,てすと,2011
2,テスト,2012
3,test,
4,TEST,2015
●実行結果
0 : no
1 : title
2 : year

0 : 1
1 : 縺ｦ縺吶→
2 : 2011

0 : 2
1 : 繝�繧ｹ繝�
2 : 2012

0 : 3
1 : test
2 :

0 : 4
1 : TEST
2 : 2015

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\CSVデータ_utf8.txt");
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
            InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(input,"UTF-8");
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(stream);

            String line;

            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {

                byte[] b = line.getBytes();
                line = new String(b, "SJIS");
                String[] columns = line.split(",",-1);

                for (int j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(j + " : " + columns[j]);
                }

                System.out.println("");

            }

            input.close();
            stream.close();
            buffer.close();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: サクラエディタを使用しているということなので、windowsのユーザーであると思いますが、windowsのコンソールの出力はシフトＪＩＳなのでwindows環境で実行している場合出力時に変換する必要はないように思います。つまり`byte[] b = line.getBytes();
                line = new String(b, "SJIS");`を削除すればいいと思います。

Comment: ご丁寧な返信ありがとうございます。byte[] b = line.getBytes(); line = new String(b, "SJIS");を削除すればいいとのことですがそれだとＣＳＶファイルの文字コード「UTF-8」をSJISに変換しないことになってしまうと思います。
これからの実装として、「UTF-8」をSJISに変換してＤＢにＣＳＶファイルの内容を入れようとも考えていますのでSJISに変換して文字化けしないようにしたいです。文字化けしないようにコードを修正したいのですが何か案はございますでしょうか。

Comment: ファイルのエンコードとjavaの内部で扱っているエンコードがあって、エンコードを指定してファイルの読み込みができた時点でjava内部で扱うコードに変換されています。それを標準的に出力する場合には出力として例えばシフトＪＩＳで出力されるというという意味です。ファイルに出力する場合にOutputStreamWriterのエンコーダーを指定するとちょうど読込の反対の処理、内部表現を出力のエンコードに変換して出力するということになります。読み込んだ文字列を明示的に変換する必要がないというのはそういう意味です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

基本的にはBLUEPIXYさんのコメント通りに2行のコードを削るだけなのですが、「windowsのコンソールの出‌​力はシフトＪＩＳなので」と言うのはちょっと違うので、その点を補足しておきます。

まずは、JavaのデフォルトエンコーディングがUTF-8となっているMac環境で、あなたのコードそのまま(ファイルパスだけはMac用に修正しました)を実行した結果です。

> ```
> 0 : no
> 1 : title
> 2 : year
>
> 0 : 1
> 1 : 縺ｦ縺吶→
> 2 : 2011
>
> 0 : 2
> 1 : 繝�繧ｹ繝�
> 2 : 2012
>
> 0 : 3
> 1 : test
> 2 : 
>
> 0 : 4
> 1 : TEST
> 2 : 2015
> ```

どんな文字に化けるかまで含めて、結果が完全に同じことがわかるかと思います。

では、何が起こっているかを2行目の「1,てすと,2011」について示しておきます。

まず、`line = "1,てすと,2011"`となっている状態で、`byte[] b = line.getBytes();`が実行されると、`b`の内容は以下のようなバイト列になります。(*1)

> ```
> 31 2C E3 81 A6 E3 81 99 E3 81 A8 2C 32 30 31 31
>  1  , <--て--> <--す--> <--と-->  ,  2  0  1  1
> ```

(ひらがなや漢字(*2)はUTF-8では3バイトになります。Macではコード引用しても全角文字が半角文字の倍にはならないので、環境によっては上下の行の対応が大きくずれて見えているかもしれません、ひらがなが3バイト、その他が1バイトで対応させながらみてください。)

次の行の`line = new String(b, "SJIS");`では、そのバイト列を無理やりShift_JISとして解釈させようとしているので、次のような形になります。

> ```
> 31 2C E3 81 A6 E3 81 99 E3 81 A8 2C 32 30 31 31
>  1  , <縺 > ｦ  <縺 > <吶 > <→ >  ,  2  0  1  1
> ```

以下のバイト列(Shift_JISでは、漢字は2バイト、半角カタカナは1バイト)が「正しく」変換されているのがわかります。

E3 81: 縺
A6:    ｦ
99 E3: 吶
81 A8: →

[文字コード表 シフトJIS(Shift_JIS)](http://charset.7jp.net/sjis.html)
(検索でたまたまトップに出ただけのサイトを掲載していますが、誤りはないと思います。)

---

と言うわけで、Javaが保持している文字列は正しくコンソールに表示されているようですので、

***どう修正すれば文字化けがなくコンソール表示できるのでしょうか。***

と言う質問に対する答えはBLUEPIXYさんのコメントやuser20098さんの回答の最後にもありますが、次の2行を削除してやれば良いと言うことになります。

```
            byte[] b = line.getBytes();
            line = new String(b, "SJIS");
```

文字エンコーディングの詳細を丸暗記するのは不可能ですが、具体的にバイト列と文字列の間の変換とは何が起こっているのかを意識すれば、理解しやすくなるかと思います。「文字化け」の仕組みがよく理解できない場合だけでも、文字コード表とにらめっこしてみてください。

*1 結果がMacと全く同じなので、UTF-8のバイト列を出力しているはずです。
*2 昔のJISコードにある漢字の場合3バイト、その後追加された漢字については4バイトの場合もあります。

Comment: ご丁寧な返信ありがとうございます。byte[] b = line.getBytes(); line = new String(b, "SJIS");を削除すればいいとのことですがそれだとＣＳＶファイルの文字コード「UTF-8」をSJISに変換しないことになってしまうと思います。
これからの実装として、「UTF-8」をSJISに変換してＤＢにＣＳＶファイルの内容を入れようとも考えていますのでSJISに変換して文字化けしないようにしたいです。
文字化けしないようにコードを修正したいのですが何か案はございますでしょうか。

Comment: @kazu さん、[もう一つの文字コードに関するご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/34491/13972)にも補足を書きましたので、そちらもご参照ください。「案」と言うよりもJavaではこれ以外にはないと言う形ですが、一旦正しくJava文字列として読み込まれたら、通常自前で文字コード変換の処理を行うことはありません。DBの方がSJISで格納しなければならないのであれば(ちょっと今時の設計としてはあり得ないような気がしますが)、DBを操作するクラスに「SJISで格納するよう設定」するだけです。「SJISに変換」するようなコードを自分で書くことはありません。もう少し具体的なことは、実際のコードを含めたご質問をお書きいただければ、回答できる方はたくさんおられると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。すいません、最後に質問させてくだい。「byte[] b = line.getBytes();line = new String(b, "SJIS");」を削除して「line = new String(line.getBytes("SJIS"),"SJIS");」を削除した箇所に追加したら文字化けすることなく表示されました。追加したコードはUTF-8のデータをを無理やりShift_JISとして解釈させようとしているわけではないのでしょうか。

Comment: 追加されたコードは「Javaの文字列をSJISのバイト列に変換する」「SJISのバイト列をJavaの文字列に変換する」の動作をしているので、「何もしない」と同じことです。その行は追加しなくても文字化けせずに表示されるはずです。JavaではUTF-8を指定して読み込んだ文字列はJava文字列としての内部表現に変換されており、追加された行を実行する前の`line`はUTF-8とは関係ないただのJava文字列です。一度Javaの`String`として読み込まれたらUTF-8もSJISもない、ただのJava文字列になっているのだと思ってください。

Comment: 理解できました。何ども下手な質問申し訳ありません。また何か質問があるときはぜひともよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

[Javaの文字コード変換の文字化けについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34483/java%e3%81%ae%e6%96%87%e5%ad%97%e3%82%b3%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e5%a4%89%e6%8f%9b%e3%81%ae%e6%96%87%e5%ad%97%e5%8c%96%e3%81%91%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6) にも書かせてもらいましたが、
`java.io.PrintStream#println`の挙動によるものと思います。(文字列をデフォルトエンコーディングで変換して出力しているため)

独自にSJISデータを出力するのであれば、`java.io.OutputStream#write`メソッドでバイト列を出力するとよいと思います。

```
    // コード例 (出力部分)
    for (int j = 0; j < colummns.length; j++) {
        System.out.write((j + " : " + column[j]).getBytes("ISO8859_1"));
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

ちなみに、提示例なら読み込んだ文字列を単に`System.out.println`で出力すれば期待する結果になると思います。